# Feed restier from external DBcontext

Tags: data-access-layer, restier

I have separate DAL and need to feed restier controller from it.
Is it possible to use dbcontext from another assembly ?

also I am trying it but getting error on connection string to dbcontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible.
You just have to register your dbContext as service in serviceCollection.
Your problem with connection string isn't related to RESTier at all.

```
public static new IServiceCollection ConfigureApi(Type apiType, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddScoped<DbContext>(sp => 
          {
            return GetYourInitializedDbContextFromAnywhereYouWant();
          });
    }
```